# Sequelize: Unhandled rejection Error: Both `replacements` and `bind` cannot be set at the same time

Tags: node.js, angular, express, sequelize.js

In Sequelize (REST API on EXPRESS) only in POST (CREATE) request, i calling API Route which call function from controller where I use: creating instance with associations, model + association + route look fine, but i got error:

Error: Both `replacements` and `bind` cannot be set at the same time

I cant solve this, a spent a lot of time about this error, yet.

Please can anybody help me with this?

I tried:

middleware error handler with return async, same result.

Remove "freezeTableName", nothing changed.

```
config.js:

const AddressModel = require('../model/address.model');
const CompanyModel = require('../model/company.model');

const Address = AddressModel(sequelize, Sequelize);
const Company = CompanyModel(sequelize, Sequelize);

Company.belongsTo(Address);

....

router.js:

module.exports = function (app) {

    let company = require('../controllers/company.controller.js');

    // Create a new Customer
    app.post('/api/company', company.createCompany);

....


company.controller.js:

const db = require('../config/db.config.js');
const Company = db.Company;
const Address = db.Address;

// Post a Company
exports.createCompany = async (req, res) => {
    const transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();
    try {
        let company = await Company.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            Address: {
                whole_address: 'TEST ADDRESS FIELD',
                ruian_adm_code: 126252
            }
        }, {
            include: [Address],
            transaction
        });
        await transaction.commit();
        if (company) {
            res.json({
                success: 1,
                data: company,
                message: 'Company created.'
            });
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        await transaction.rollback();
        res.json({success: 0, message: ex});
    }
};

....
```

RETURN = Error: Both `replacements` and `bind` cannot be set at the same time

Comment: Are you sure this error is related to the attached code snippets? Replacements and binds in sequelize are related to raw queries. You're not executing a single raw query here.

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk: THX! you give me right way, the problem was in global configuration: RAW: TRUE, i forgot this part of code in config.js. Its solved.